# Repmat function in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have been through a bunch of questions about the Repeat function in MatLab, but I can't figure out how this process work.

I am trying to translate it into R, but my problem is that I do not know how the function manipulates the data.

The code is part of a process to make a pairs trading strategy, where the code takes in a vector of FALSE/TRUE expressions.

The code is:

```
% initialize positions array 
positions=NaN(length(tday), 2);

% long entries
positions(shorts, :)=repmat([-1 1], [length(find(shorts)) 1]);
```

where shorts is the vector of TRUE/FALSE expressions.

Hope you can help.

Comment: http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~cs1173/resources/CS1173RepmatFunction.pdf

Comment: http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/octave-r.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`repmat`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) repeats the matrix you give him `[dim1 dim2 dim3,...]` times. What your code does is:

**1.-**`length(find(shorts))`: gets the amount of "trues" in `shorts`.

e.g:

```
shorts=[1 0 0 0 1 0]
length(find(shorts))
ans = 2
```

**2.-**`repmat([-1 1], [length(find(shorts)) 1]);` repeats the `[-1 1]` `[length(find(shorts)) 1]` times.

continuation of e.g.:

```
repmat([-1 1], [length(find(shorts)) 1]);
ans=[-1 1
     -1 1];
```

**3.-** `positions(shorts, :)=` saves the given matrix in the given indexes. (NOTE!: only works if `shorts` is of type `logical`).

continuation of e.g.:

At this point, if you haven't omit anything, positions should be a `6x2` `NaN` matrix. the indexing will fill the `true` positions of `shorts` with the `[-1 1]` matrix. so after this, positions will be:

```
positions=[-1 1
           NaN NaN
           NaN NaN
           NaN NaN
           -1 1
           NaN NaN]
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much for you help Ander. Just what I needed to figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

The MATLAB [`repmat`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) function replicates and tiles the array. The syntax is

```
B = repmat(A,n)
```

where `A` is the input array and `n` specifies how to tile the array. If `n` is a vector `[n1,n2]` - as in your case - then `A` is replicated `n1` times in rows and `n2` times in columns. E.g.

```
A = [ 1 2 ; 3 4]
B = repmat(A,[2,3])

B =           |           |
     1     2     1     2     1     2
     3     4     3     4     3     4   __
     1     2     1     2     1     2
     3     4     3     4     3     4
```

(the lines are only to illustrate how `A` gets tiled)

In your case, `repmat` replicates the vector `[-1, 1]` for each non-zero element of `shorts`. You thus set each row of `positions`, whos corresponding entry in `shorts` is not zero, to `[-1,1]`. All other rows will stay `NaN`.

For example if

```
shorts = [1; 0; 1; 1; 0];
```

then your code will create

```
positions = 
          -1    1
          NaN   NaN
          -1    1
          -1    1
          NaN   NaN
```

I hope this helps you to clarify the effect of `repmat`. If not, feel free to ask.

Comment: You are 2 seconds faster than me! ;)